Invoke Powershell to zip Archive a folder from C# app with native progress UI

The Compress-Archive command was found in the module Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive, but the module could not be loaded.For more information, run Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.

I'm trying to invoke powershell to archive a specific folder from a C# WPF application; I'm hoping to have the progress UI from winzip show status of archive to user while running.
string psScript = @"$Target = 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\Test.zip'; $Source = 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\temp'; Compress-Archive -Path $Source -DestinationPath $Target";
                using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    ps.AddScript(psScript);
                    ps.Invoke();

                }

The powershell call always returns the following error:
"The 'Compress-Archive' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive'"
Any direction would be hugely appreciated, not well ensconced in powershell.

Could be useful to see how your csproj looks like but also I'd advise against using Compress-Archive to begin with. It will be easier to add progress bar to your wpf app if you rewrite the logic to zip directories, you can use this as an example: https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression/blob/main/src/PSCompression/Commands/CompressZipArchiveCommand.cs

Is powershell necessary, or the main objective is create zip while showing progress from C#?
